# Using Bottleneck to rate-limit API requests in a library

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, asynchronous, rate-limiting

I am writing an API wrapper in TypeScript. I would like the code to be asynchronous in order to maximally meet the rate limit of the API in question. The API wants requests to be submitted at a maximum rate of 1/second.

I intend to implement an API wrapper which is instantiated once, and allows the use of objects to reach the different endpoints. For instance, within the greater API there is a `post` and `pool` endpoint. I would like to access them like `post_object.post.submit_request(argument1, ...)` or `post_object.pool.submit_request(argument1, ...)`.

I have created an object called `state_info` which is passed between the various objects, within which is contained a user-agent header, login information if provided, and a rate-limiter object from the Bottleneck library.

The issue I'm running into while testing is that my program doesn't seem to actually be limiting the rate of requests; no matter what I change the limit to in the arguments for Bottleneck, the requests all happen in about .600 seconds every time.

I am thinking this has something to do with passing around the rate-limiter object, or in accessing it from multiple places, but I'm unsure.

First, here is the code for the `Model` object, which represents access into the API.

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { StateInfo, Method } from "./interfaces";

export class Model {
  public stateInfo: StateInfo;

  constructor(stateInfo: StateInfo) {
    // Preserve rate limiter, user agent, etc.
    this.stateInfo = stateInfo;
  }

  //Updated to funcName = () => {} syntax to bind "this" to this class context.
  private submit_request = (query_url: string, method: Method) => {
    if (this.stateInfo.username && this.stateInfo.api_key) {
      const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: method,
        url: query_url,
        headers: { "User-Agent": this.stateInfo.userAgent },
        auth: {
          username: this.stateInfo.username,
          password: this.stateInfo.api_key,
        },
      };
      return axios(axiosConfig);
    }  else {
      const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: "get",
        url: query_url,
        headers: { "User-Agent": this.stateInfo.userAgent },
      };

      return axios(axiosConfig);
    }
  };

  public submit_throttled_request = (url: string, method: Method) => {
    return this.stateInfo.rateLimiter.schedule(
      this.submit_request,
      url,
      method
    );
  };
}
```

Then, the code from which I call this class:

```
import { Model } from "./models/model";
import Bottleneck from "bottleneck";

const limiter: Bottleneck = new Bottleneck({ mintime: 1000, maxconcurrent: 1 });

const stateInfo = {
  rateLimiter: limiter,
  userAgent: "email@website.com | API Dev",
};

let modelObj: Model = new Model(stateInfo);

async function makeRequest() {
  try {
    let response = await modelObj.submit_throttled_request(
      "https://www.website.com/api",
      "get"
    );
    console.log(response.data.id + "|" + Date.now());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

let start = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  makeRequest();
}
```

My expectation is that the operation would take, at a minimum, 10 seconds if only one request can be submitted per second. Yet I'm averaging half that, no matter what I include for `mintime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've learned the answer to my own question after much head-scratching.

It turns out, in the ["gotchas"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck#gotchas--common-mistakes) section of the [bottleneck API reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck#gotchas--common-mistakes) they note:

> If you're passing an object's method as a job, you'll probably need to bind() the object:

with the following code:

```
// instead of this:
limiter.schedule(object.doSomething);
// do this:
limiter.schedule(object.doSomething.bind(object));
// or, wrap it in an arrow function instead:
limiter.schedule(() => object.doSomething());
```

This is the issue into which I was running. I was handing off `axios(axiosContext)` without binding the scope, so nothing was being sent off to the bottleneck ratelimiter. By wrapping is like so: `this.state_info.rateLimiter.schedule(() => axios(axiosContext));` I have managed to correctly bind the context as needed.